# Visual Studio 2022 17.4.0 Preview 1 not installing

Tags: visual-studio, installation

[image]

[image]

I tried restarting my pc but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I can install Visual Studio 2022 17.4.0 Preview 1 correctly, because I don't have the old  preview in my computer.

Uninstall the old version of community 2022 preview and then install Visual Studio 2022 17.4.0 Preview 1 from [this page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/zh-hans/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?ch=pre&sku=community&channel=Preview&version=VS2022&source=VSLandingPage&cid=2030&passive=false) should fix the problem.

If you don't want to uninstall the old preview, you can try to provide feedback via the button in the lower left corner.